# How to prevent django tests from showing sys.stdout messages?

Tags: python, django, nose, django-nose

My problem is that since I have added logging to my django app when I run my unit tests all my log messages show in the console. I use nose as test runner. Its usual behaviour was to capture `sys.stdout`, only show console output if a test failed and show it at the end.

I used to have this output when running my tests:

```
........
Ran 8 tests in 0.876s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

This is the output I am getting now when I run `python manage.py test accounts`:

```
...log message
.log message
....log message
Ran 8 tests in 1.034s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

This has started happening when I have added logging using Python standard logging library to my code. I changed my `settings.py` and `views.py`. Below you can check what I have changed exactly.

Can someone help me keep my logging but avoid the annoying extra output when I run tests?

**Added to `settings.py`**

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': 'INFO',
            'stream': sys.stdout,
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

**Added to my views**

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.info("log message")
```

**The command django uses to run my tests**

```
nosetests accounts/ --with-coverage --cover-package=accounts,keys, utils --cover-html --cover-erase --logging-filter='selenium' --verbosity=1
```

**Configuration of nose test runner in `settings.py` (this was the same when it was working)**

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
NOSE_ARGS = [
    '--with-coverage',
    '--cover-package=accounts,keys, utils',
    '--cover-html',
    '--cover-erase',
    "--logging-filter='selenium'",
]
```

Comment: I think it may be your `--logging-filter` do you need to include selenium logs?

Comment: I´m not sure if understand what you mean. Do you mean to add something else to my logging-filter? Can you explain what exactly and how you would do it? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write a custom test runner to disable logging or change the level.

```
import logging

from django_nose import NoseTestSuiteRunner


class DisableLoggingNoseTestSuiteRunner(NoseTestSuiteRunner):
    """
    Disable the test runner log level below `logging.CRITICAL`.
    """
    def run_tests(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Disable logging below critical
        logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)
        super(DisableLoggingNoseTestSuiteRunner, self).run_tests(*args, **kwargs)
```

You also have to change your `settings.py`to use that test runner.

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'package_where_you_place_it.DisableLoggingNoseTestSuiteRunner'
```